# How to prompt a banner on mobile web to promote users to download the app instead?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, smartbanner

The website is developed with React. When users open my website on an iPhone or an Android phone, how to show a banner to promote the user to download or use the IOS or Android app instead of the website on a browser?

Here is an example with reddit.com, when opening reddit.com on an iPhone or an Android phone, it shows a banner like these to promote the users to use the Reddit ios or android app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related as I believe the terminology changed from "smartbanner" to "app links" and "universal links": https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6046977

Comment: @Morrison Chang is this something that needs to be done on the mobile codebase or website codebase?

Comment: Both in mobile app and website need to be configured (presumably for security reasons).

Comment: What kind of configuration? Does this bottom sheet as shown in the screenshot something that require coding or it comes with the IOS or Android OS as long as it's configured?

Comment: Documentation is in the links listed in my link. To my understanding the bottom sheet is part of OS/Chrome/Safari browser.

Comment: Just checking if you found: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ or https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/DeepLinking but it may depend on what React libraries the website is using which you don't specify.

Comment: @MorrisonChang The website is using React. I have the deep-linking part figured out. You mentioned the bottom sheet is part of OS/Chrome/Safari browser, do you have reference or doc links for how to make that happen?

Comment: Have you read the links on the page linked to in my first comment? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html If they are insufficient to explain how to get the 'disambiguation dialog' please update your post with what you've tried (or perhaps a different detailed question with what you are blocked/confused/unsure about). Or if about install have you seen: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/

Comment: For ios Install see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners

Answer (score 0):

On the opening of the website on the mobile browser, you can detect the device using the JS library [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect).

if it's Android or iPhone/iPad you can show the banner and with the click of that button, you can use the Deeplink URLs for the android and iOS app. You can also use [dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) if you want to send users to AppStore or Play Store.

Comment: How to show the banner, is it something that has to be coded up or it's something that can be configured?

Comment: You can provide custom way or you can use this for the banner: https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner

Answer (score 0):

you can use on your website : [https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform](https://Extension)

You can show a popup according to the relevant situation and send it with a dynamic link.

Comment: The link doesn't work.